# Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to write a program where a user can create a time table in Python using Tkinter. Right now, I'm trying to setup the GUI for basically the "main menu" where the user can click the button and bring up another window or whatever is necessary for the next task. However, my program automatically runs what I have under the functions. How do I go about fixing this? I can't find any results when I try to google because many don't show how to define the GUI as a class.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


def loadTable():
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("allfiles","*")])
def addCourse():
    print("Insert functionality here")
def addTime():
    print("Insert functionality here")
def resetTable():
    print("Insert functionality here")
def addComment():
    print("Insert functionality here")
def viewTable():
    print("Insert functionality here")


class menu():
    app = Tk()
    app.geometry("800x600+200+200")
    app.title("Time Tracker")
    #load the buttons for UI
    bLoad = Button(app, text = "Load Table", command = loadTable())
    bCourse = Button(app, text = "Add Course", command = addCourse())
    bTime = Button(app, text = "Add Time", command = addTime())
    bReset = Button(app, text = "Reset Time", command = resetTable())
    bComment = Button(app, text = "Add Comment", command = addComment())
    bView = Button(app, text = "View Table", command = viewTable())
    bLoad.pack(side="top", anchor = "w", padx=15, pady=35)
    bCourse.pack(side="top", anchor = "w", padx=15, pady=35)
    bTime.pack(side="top", anchor = "w", padx=15, pady=35)
    bReset.pack(side="top", anchor = "w", padx=15, pady=35)
    bComment.pack(side="top", anchor = "w",  padx=15, pady=35)
    bView.pack(side="top", anchor = "w", padx=15, pady=35)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

Comment: More code is needed. The code that you've provided doesn't convey much to generate the same undesired behavior as you are getting.

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil Basically I want the buttons to call to a function when I click them. However, all the functions run when I run the program in this state so my idle shell gets all the print statements and the file manager pops up. I basically want to fix that at this point. However, I plan on possibly making one of these buttons open a new window to add information to my table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have **called** the function with your button. It doesn't wait till the button is pressed. The functions are called automatically.

Try this

```
bLoad = Button(app, text = "Load Table", command = loadTable)
bCourse = Button(app, text = "Add Course", command = addCourse)
bTime = Button(app, text = "Add Time", command = addTime)
bReset = Button(app, text = "Reset Time", command = resetTable)
bComment = Button(app, text = "Add Comment", command = addComment)
bView = Button(app, text = "View Table", command = viewTable)
```

Comment: @WorldDominator kindly accept the answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: Sorry I was busy. It worked. Thanks! I thought I had changed that around before and noticed no difference.

Comment: try not to use hit & trial. It never helps

Comment: I usually do it when it's something unfamiliar to me. Do you suggest looking purely at syntax or something?

Comment: Even if you are trying something unfamiliar,try to understand what you are doing. That way,in future,you would be quickly able to assess your code to check where the bugs are.

Answer (score 0):

```
bLoad = Button(app, text = "Load Table", command = loadTable)
bCourse = Button(app, text = "Add Course", command = addCourse)
bTime = Button(app, text = "Add Time", command = addTime)
bReset = Button(app, text = "Reset Time", command = resetTable)
bComment = Button(app, text = "Add Comment", command = addComment)
bView = Button(app, text = "View Table", command = viewTable)
```